# My Step definitions log snippets are not getting generated from my feature file

Tags: cucumber

I expect Step definitions snipped to get generate when I run my feature file which isn't happening

I have tried to run my feature file as Cucumber Feature and also tried to run my Test Runner file; in either case log snippets for my step definition class are not getting generated.

My Runner Class Is

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="/Users/bhabanimishra/Documents/workspace/CucTest/src/test/java/Feature",
        glue={"stepDefinition"}
        )
public class TestRunner {

}
```

My Feature file is as below

```
  @smokeTest
  Scenario: Creating shamba
     Given: I am in shamba Page
     And: Add new button is enabled
     When: I click on Add New Button
     Then: Shamba Popup Should open
     When: I enter all the data in popup
     And: Click On Save Button
     Then: Shamba should be successfully created
```

Expected Step definitions logs to be generated

Actual
Undefined scenarios:
/Users/bhabanimishra/Documents/workspace/CucTest/src/test/java/Feature/test1.feature:22 # Ceating shamba

0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.331s

enter image description here

Comment: Try removing the colon (`:`) after the keywords at the start of your steps (Given, And, When, Then

Comment: And/or try replacing to following in the runner: `features="src/test/java/Feature"` or better yet, place your feature files in `src/test/resources/features` and provide that link. Check the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) to help you get started